# How to Upload file from local with Cypress

Tags: javascript, file-upload, upload, cypress

I'm new to Cypress, and i'm facing issues trying to upload a file.

I have a form which looks like this,

[image]

It will open a window form to select files to Upload.

So, How to I select a file and upload with this window form ?

I tried following the steps in the [git issue](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/170) but could get it to work.

I was looking into having the files stored in fixtures to allow easier access. (but not sure if this is correct)

Any help would be great

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is not yet implemented, see this open issue: [issue link](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/170). 
There are however some *hacky* ways around that, and some third party packages that might help: [cypress upload](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cypress-file-upload)